# Running an HTTP request in the middle of an observable stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a relatively simple HTTP PUT request:

```
const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', payload.url, payload.file, {
  reportProgress: true,
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'),
});

return self.http.request(req).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  switch (event.type) {
    case HttpEventType.Sent:
      console.log('Request sent!');
      break;
    case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
      console.log('Response header received!');
      break;
    case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
      const kbLoaded = Math.round(event.loaded / 1024);
      console.log(`Download in progress! ${kbLoaded}Kb loaded`);
      break;
    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
      const kbUploaded = Math.round(event.loaded / 1024);
      console.log(`Upload in progress! ${kbUploaded}Kb loaded`);
      break;
    case HttpEventType.Response:
      console.log(' Done!', event.body);
      return payload;
  }
});
```

How can I insert this into an observable stream, such that I can pipe previous responses into it and await sending the next response until the upload is complete? I've tried the following:

1. Wrapping the entire thing in a `.do(payload => { ... } )`

This sort of works - the statement fires as expected, and the file is uploaded - but the functions downstream don't wait until the upload is complete, so I can't pass the result in any way. It also feels hacky, as the docs imply that `.do()` is more for logging and minor utility than tasks central to the entire function.

2. Using `map` and `flatMap` to attempt to fit it into the stream

I also tried splitting up the request functionality into a couple of functions like this:

```
...
.flatMap(payload => {
  const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', payload.url, payload.file, {
    reportProgress: true,
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'),
  });

  return self.http.request(req).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    return { ...payload, event };
  });
})
.map(payload => {
  switch (payload.event.type) {
    case HttpEventType.Sent:
      console.log('Request sent!');
      break;
    case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
      console.log('Response header received!');
      break;
    case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
      const kbLoaded = Math.round(payload.event.loaded / 1024);
      console.log(`Download in progress! ${kbLoaded}Kb loaded`);
      break;
    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
      const kbUploaded = Math.round(payload.event.loaded / 1024);
      console.log(`Upload in progress! ${kbUploaded}Kb loaded`);
      break;
    case HttpEventType.Response:
      console.log(' Done!', payload.event.body);
      return [];
  }
})
```

The upload works, but the observable ends up sending a response for every single HttpEvent, which isn't what I want. I want to only send a response when the upload is finished, aka `HttpEventType.Response`.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I do it right?

Comment: What do you have that follows the final `map` in your number 2 snippet? It could be that you have an error occurring, as all of the cases apart from `HttpEventType.Response` will see `undefined` emitted from the `map` and into the observable stream.

Comment: I had a `map` function that checked if all of the provided files were uploaded, and returned a result if they were. I tried commenting it out and just returning an empty variable, and the request started going through. Does putting a `return` statement within an `if` block break the stream somehow?

Comment: It's difficult to understand the question. I think you need to add all of the relevant code.

Comment: I don't know what the other relevant code is supposed to look like because I don't know how to structure this kind of observable. That's why I'm asking this question. With that said, getting rid of literally everything after snippet 2 and just returning an empty array (the entire observable is for an array of variables) makes the request work, but I want to filter events so that it only responds when the upload is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you elect to not return a value from the function passed to `map`, it will do what any other JavaScript function will do and will return `undefined`.

So all of the cases except for `HttpEventType.Response` will see `undefined` emitted into the observable stream.

If you want to ignore the emitted value for the other cases, use `filter`:

```
.map(payload => {
  switch (payload.event.type) {
    case HttpEventType.Sent:
      console.log('Request sent!');
      break;
    case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
      console.log('Response header received!');
      break;
    case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
      const kbLoaded = Math.round(payload.event.loaded / 1024);
      console.log(`Download in progress! ${kbLoaded}Kb loaded`);
      break;
    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
      const kbUploaded = Math.round(payload.event.loaded / 1024);
      console.log(`Upload in progress! ${kbUploaded}Kb loaded`);
      break;
    case HttpEventType.Response:
      console.log(' Done!', payload.event.body);
      return [];
  }
})
.filter(value => Boolean(value)) // filter undefined values
```

However, it would be clearer if you always returned a result, rather than rely upon an implict `undefined`:

```
.map(payload => {
  switch (payload.event.type) {
    case HttpEventType.Sent:
      console.log('Request sent!');
      return payload;
    case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
      console.log('Response header received!');
      return payload;
    case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
      const kbLoaded = Math.round(payload.event.loaded / 1024);
      console.log(`Download in progress! ${kbLoaded}Kb loaded`);
      return payload;
    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
      const kbUploaded = Math.round(payload.event.loaded / 1024);
      console.log(`Upload in progress! ${kbUploaded}Kb loaded`);
      return payload;
    case HttpEventType.Response:
      console.log(' Done!', payload.event.body);
      return { ...payload, body: payload.event.body }; // or whatever
  }
})
.filter(payload => payload.event.type === HttpEventType.Response)
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for. I didn't realize I was emitting `undefined` when not returning anything because it seemed like execution just stopped without any errors in my IDE, but now I understand what's happening. I ended up going with the latter option you suggested.